# .htaccess-The page isn't redirecting properly

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect **index.html** to **home.html** and also remove that *home.html* from url via .htaccess. But it shows The page isn't redirecting properly.
Which Means i need to redirect mydomain.com/index.html to mydomain.com/home.html  and I need to show mydomain.com/ only when I visit index page.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 "/index.html" "/home.html"

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*home\.html [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)home\.html/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could try instead of utilizing mod_rewrite is setting **[DirectoryIndex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html)** to the desired page (in your case home.html):

```
DirectoryIndex home.html
```

So, if you're calling `domain.com/` it should give you the contents of `domain.com/home.html`

For reference, the Apache configuration manual:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html
"DirectoryIndex Directive"

---

Referencing the conversation right below:

Maybe this could work (Sorry, I cant test it right now)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/index.html
RewriteRule (.*?)home\.html/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

A bit of explanation: If the requested host matches example.com and the called URI is in fact not a real file or folder plus the URI equals to
"index.html" it should redirect to home.html.

**EDIT**: As you dont want to show the home.html we can maybe get away by "proxying" the request internally instead of forcing an external redirect. Try to replace "R=301" in the last line (the RewriteRule) with "P" so it says `RewriteRule (.*?)home\.html/*(.*) /$1$2 [P,NE,L]`

Comment: I also tried  DirectoryIndex home.html but it changes all index.html from directory. I mean subdomains. So I need only for specific domain.

Comment: If i understand this correctly, you only want this to happen on a specific domain but non on subdomains of this domain?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: c1nema Its working but shows mydomain.com/home.html. But I need only mydomain.com in URL

Answer (score 0):

// It's working code i hope it's useful ..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com/
</IfModule>
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?http://dbdenterprise\.in$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dbdenterprise.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```